# Magento 2: Get Product via url with sku number in url

Tags: product-urls, magento2.2.9

I have a magento 2.2.9 based site and wondering if its possible to get a product via url by having the sku in the url?

so something like https://www.domain.com/shop/?sku=123

Wanted to know if there is a default way to do this that wouldn't require building any custom module.

Comment: How do you mean "get the product"? Do you want to fetch the data or do you want to go to the product page itself? 

In the first case take a look at the Magento API : https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/rest/bk-rest.html

Comment: I mean so if someone wants to share a link to the product with a friend this is specific to configurable products say they want to send there friend a email to the specific product (the large blue shirt with a crew neck) .

Comment: You can retrieve the value of ?sku by using PHP.  Start your code with $yourvariable=$_GET['sku'];

Comment: @Jayreis : have you got the soln?

Comment: No the solutions below all are for creating a module that would then load a custom page with the product info. However I want people to click a link and go to the default product detail page with the specific configuration loaded based on a sku variable thats in the url.

Answer (score 1):

**Try below code:**

If Url like this https://www.domain.com/shop/?sku=123, then

**Using Construct Method:**

```
...
private $productRepository; 

protected $request;
...
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    $this->request = $request;
    ...
}

public function loadMyProduct()
{
    $params = $this->request->getParams(); // all params
    if(is_array($params['sku']) && count($params) > 0){
        $proSku  = isset($params['sku']) ? $params['sku'] : '';
        $product = $this->productRepository->get($proSku);
        return $product;
    }
    return '';
}
...
```

**Using Object Manager**

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
$request       = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http');
$params        = $request->getParams();
$productRepository = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface');
$product = $productRepository->get($params['sku']);
echo "pro name".$product->getName()." == ".$product->getPrice();
```

**Note:** Magento did not recommend the **Object Manager Method**

**I hope it will helps...!!!**